# Setting the number of hadoop tasks/node

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am running a Hadoop job on a cluster that is shared by several of our applications. We have about 40 nodes and 4 mapper slots/node. Whenever my job (which is nothing but mapper) runs, it takes up all the 160 slots and blocks other jobs from running. I have tried to set the property from within the job "mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=1" and also "mapred.map.tasks" to 30 (to limit it to only 30 nodes) from with the task code.

```
    conf.setInt ( "mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum", 1 );
    conf.setInt ( "mapred.map.tasks", 30 );
    conf.setBoolean ( "mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution", false );
```

I have 2 questions:

a. When the job runs, the job.xml reflects the "mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=1", but the job still ends up taking 160 slots.

b. The mapred.map.tasks in the job.xml is not 30. It is still a big number (like 800).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it's best to control the maximum number of mappers by setting the input files' block size when moving data into HDFS. For example, if you set the block size to 1/30 of the total size, you'll end up with 30 blocks, and therefore, a maximum of 30 map tasks.

> hadoop fs -D fs.local.block.size=134217728 -put local_name remote_location

Answer (score 0):

We can specify max and min map tasks for job but hadoop dosent guarantee its execution like it does for reducers. Hadoop uses the min and max map task values to estimate and does its best to keep number of tasks close to it.You should use a scheduler like fair scheduler in cluster for your problem. Fair scheduling is a method of assigning resources to jobs such that all jobs get, on average, an equal share of resources over time.

Answer (score 0):

you can not limit the number of the mapper number.

The mapper number is counted by your data size and the block size.If your data is very large，you only can increase you block size to reduce the mapper number.

Because if you limit the number,the mapper will block for waiting for  the end of all other mappers .